# Negate isin - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following line in my code where I group df based on a column `Package`, and calculate the size of each group based on a criteria on another column `Id`.

```
df.groupby("Package")["Id"].apply(lambda x: x.isin(someList).sum())
Package
P1       1
P2       12
P3       52
P4       123
P5       5421
P6       53
P7       64
Name: Id, dtype: int64
```

My question is that I also need to calculate the size of each group where `x` is not in `someList`. How can I do that? Should I just tilde somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution add `~` with parentheses to lambda function:

```
df.groupby("Package")["Id"].apply(lambda x: (~x.isin(someList)).sum())
```

Or use syntactic sugar - create `Series` of not membership and aggregate by Series `df["Package"]`:

```
(~df["Id"].isin(someList)).groupby(df["Package"]).sum()
```

Similar cleaner idea with column `Id` filled by mask, so possible aggregate with column name:

```
df.assign(Id = ~df["Id"].isin(someList)).groupby("Package")["Id"].sum()
```

Comment: That works thanks. Just started with pandas. Getting familiar with the operators and stuff.